# minted v2.2 (TeX Live 2016): changing style in the preamble does not longer work

Tags: minted, texlive-2016

I have just upgraded mi MacTeX installation to MacTeX 2016 (from '2015 with all packages updated) and I found that changing the default style using `\setminted{style=...}` in the document preamble does not longer work; now I have to include the `\setminted` command after `\begin{document}`.

For example, in this document the font size is changed, but the style is not:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{style=lovelace,fontsize=\small}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Here we go. 
\begin{minted}{python}
def fact(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    return n * fact(n-1)
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

However, if I move the `\setminted` command after `\begin{document}`, then the style is correctly changed.

TeX Live 2016 includes minted v2.2. The previous version v2.1 did not show this problem. I think that the cause resides in this line in minted.sty v2.2 and not present in v2.1:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\minted@checkstyle{}\setminted{style=default}}
```

Comment: you are probably best to ping the author here https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues

Comment: This is a bug that resulted from working on another bug. Unfortunately the initial style setup is getting a bit complicated due to the possibility of users setting a custom `pygmentize` in the preamble. Working on a fix.

Answer (score 2):

The bug is fixed in [`minted` v2.2.2](https://github.com/gpoore/minted/releases/tag/v2.2.2), which is currently on GitHub and will be on CTAN soon.